# is it safe to ignore ConcurrencyFailureException in multithreaded program, when both threads try to INSERT the same data?

Tags: sql, multithreading, oracle, spring, concurrency

In rare cases two threads try to insert the same data into the database during the same transaction. When the second thread tries to do the insert i get a Concurrency failure exception: ORA-00028: your session has been killed.. (only if the data is the same)

im using springframework.jdbc

Is it safe to catch and ignore this exception? Is there a locking mechanism in springjdbc?

Comment: How did the 'same' transaction end up with multiple threads?

Comment: Sorry, I got the terminology mixed up. I have 2 threads, two transactions inserting the same data. When the second thread tries to insert the same data a ConcurrencyFailureException occurs and i think the connection is closed. I cant just catch and ignore it because the session needs to stay open. How do i prevent this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tricky problem there. If possible, redesign your data model to avoid these concurrent inserts. Otherwise, have a look here: http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/

Comment: Alas i'm not able or allowed to redesign the data model. Thanks for the options, ill study those. I guess I was hoping Spring would have a way with dealing with this kind of concurrency.